# PHP check what array has a bigger value

Tags: php, arrays

Alright so Im trying to compare what array has bigger value but I want this code shorter, not running two `foreach` loops.

```
$one = array("test", "100");
$two = array("something", "200");

$distance1;
$distance2;

foreach($one as $val => $key) {
    $distance1 =  $val;
}

foreach($two as $val => $key) {
    $distance2 =  $val;
}

if($distance1 > $distance2)
```

Comment: Do you mean what array has more elements?

Comment: No, like as you can see test contains 100 and Something contains 200, I want to automaticly check if Test is biiger than Something (their values, on my sample you can see values 100 and 200)

Comment: Please note that your arrays both have 2 values and as from your code it looks like that you think that they have just one value. Besides that note that in your foreach loop you have `$val => $key` in the wrong order. So you maybe want to just do: `array("test" => 100)` and then you can use `"test"` as key to access the element directly like this `$one["test"]`

Comment: Your logic is flawed.

Comment: Is the numeric value always the second element? Because if so, of course a simple comparison like `$one[1] > $two[1]` would solve it, right?

Comment: The fix for this is so simple, it's almost silly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, and it's been a while since I last wrote PHP, but I love this question and I would like to suggest 4 possible approaches:

1: use the arrays that you supplied (I believe this may be what you mean)

```
$one = array("test", "100");
$two = array("something", "200");

$distance1 = $one[1];
$distance2 = $two[1];

if($distance1 > $distance2)
```

2: associative arrays, and numbers for the values

```
$one = array(
    "name" = > "test", 
    "distance" => 100
);
$two = array(
    "name" => "something", 
    "distance" => 200
);

if ($one["distance"] > $two["distance"])
```

3: Using a foreach loop with $key and $val

```
$distances = array(
    "test" => 100,
    "something" => 200
);
$highestDistance = 0;
$highest = null;

foreach ($distances as $key => $val) {
    if ($val >= highestDistance) {
        $highestDistance = $val;
        $highest = $key;
    }
}

if ($highest === 'test')
```

4: objects and sorting:

```
$distances = array(
    (object) array(
        "name" => "test", 
        "distance" => 100
    ),
    (object) array(
        "name" => "something", 
        "distance" => 200
    )
);

usort($distances, function($a, $b) { return $a - $b; });

if ($distances[0]->name === 'test')
```

Note that the conditions of the final `if` statements evaluate to `false`, as I believe is your intention (because 100 is not greater than 200).

Answer (score -2):

You Can combine the 2 arrays

```
<?php
    $one = array("test", "100");
    $two = array("something", "200");
    $result = array_merge($one , $two);
    foreach($result as $val => $key) {
       echo $val;
    }
    ?>
```